# "Unusual number of requests" error on users tab when page number is 1000 or more

Tags: bug

On the [users tab](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/users?page=1359&tab=reputation&filter=month), I can view all pages from 1 to [999](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=999&tab=reputation&filter=month). However, when the page number reaches [1000](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=1000&tab=reputation&filter=month) or more, I get an "unusual number of requests" error:

[image]

I have reproduced this on two different devices, and another user I asked was able to reproduce the error. This is a recent error, as I was able to view the last page of users as recently as January 7th, '22 (based on a screenshot I took on that date).

Comment: We observed similar behavior between `/users?page=999&tab=newusers` (which works) and `/users?page=1000&tab=newusers` (which shows the error message).