# Reputation leagues appear to be down

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues, 500-server-error

https://stackexchange.com/leagues gives an error 500.

Is this happening for everyone?

As pointed out by Glorfindel, [the leagues themselves work](https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta).

Comment: This happens to me as well.

Comment: Reproduced. The leagues themselves do work: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/year/meta

Comment: Quite possibly related to a [non-site appearing in the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375290/how-many-questions-is-nan-what-so-for-teams-is-a-qa-for-and-how-come-is).

Comment: Possibly related: ["Unusual number of requests" error on users tab when page number is 1000 or more](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/375163/unusual-number-of-requests-error-on-users-tab-when-page-number-is-1000-or-more)?